# PVC pipe back of 2story home dripping water

Tags: water, leak, pvc

Have a 2 story home on basement foundation. Have 2 AC units one in each side of house both have a pvc pipe nearby which I imagine is for condensation.

In the back of the home near the basement door and the back hose pipe there is another pvc pipe, can’t figure out what it’s for but imagine it might be some kind of overflow pipe just don’t know for what. That pipe is dripping water and had never noticed it before. When we shut the water for the outside hose that pipe continues leaking.

Does anyone know what this pipe is for and what could be causing this constant water leak/drip?

[image]

Comment: A pipe like that is usually associated with air handler condensation drainage. If you are certain it is not hooked up to an air handler drain nor  to an overflow pan under an attic mounted ac air handler, it may be attached to a water heater pressure relief valve that is leaking or to an overflow pan under a water heater that is leaking

Comment: What comes out when you open the hose bibb, with the inside shutoff valve for it open?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It’s was connected to the main line neither water heater or AC drainage, which I’m still confused as to why that is there. We added a valve to the end of pvc and that stopped the leak.